# Join Two Different Object DataType using Linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am having two lists:

```
ListA:
[
   { 
      Id = 1,
      Name = "A",
      Summary = ""
   },
   { 
      Id = 2,
      Name = "B",
      Summary = ""
   }
]

ListB: 
[
  {
    Id = 1,
    Value = "SomeThing"
  },
  {
    Id = 2,
    Value = "EveryThing"
  }
]
```

I want to join that two list using LINQ and want to return ListA which value is update as Below

```
[
   { 
      Id = 1,
      Name = "A",
      Summary = "SomeThing"
   },
   { 
      Id = 2,
      Name = "B",
      Summary = "EveryThing"
   }
]
```

I am joining ListA and ListB based on Id and assigning `value` to `summary`.
I tried below approach:

```
var query = from obj1 in ListA
            join obj2 in ListB on obj1.Id equals obj2.Id
            select obj1.Summary = obj2.Value, return obj1;
```

**=>so here i want assign data from obj2 to obj1 then want to return obj1 **

is that possible or how we can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could also update the existing ListA with a simple loop

```
foreach (var itemA in ListA)
{
    itemA.Summary = ListB.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == itemA.Id)?.Value;
}
```

---

Join approach

```
var query = ListA.Join(ListB,
                    ia => ia.Id,     
                    ib => ib.Id, 
                    (ia, ib) => new aItem() //type of ListA here
                    {
                        Id = ia.Id,
                        Name = ia.Name,
                        Summary = ib.Value
                    });
```

Comment: we have a scenario where ListC also can come then putting loop will quite confusing. we may assign summary based on concatenation of ListB and ListC object.

Comment: Take a scenario where ListA containing 10 property then we end up assigning 9 unnecessary. Can we do something where we can assign whatever is required and return ListA with an updated result?

Comment: **=>so here I want to assign data from obj2 to obj1 then want to return obj1 ** 
In this statement, i want to convey the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You could try to join the two lists like this:

```
var listA = new List<ClassA>();
var listB = new List<ClassB>();

var list = listA.Join(listB, a => a.Id, b => b.Id, (a, b) => 
            new ClassA
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                Name = a.Name,
                Summary = b.Value
            });
```

Comment: Take a scenario where ListA containing 10 property then we end up assigning 9 unnecessary. Can we do something where we can assign whatever is required and return ListA with an updated result?

Comment: You can write a foreach loop for listA and update only the _Summary_ property as @fubo recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Using method syntax Enumerable.Join is the easier one to use here:

```
var result = listA.Join(listB,    // Join ListA and ListB
    a => a.Id,                    // from every a in ListA take a.Id
    b => b.Id,                    // from every b in ListB take b.Id
    (a, b) => new                 // when they match, take the a and the b
    {                             // to create a new object with properties
        Id = a.Id,
        Name = a.Name,
        Summary = b.Value,
    });
```

Note that the result is of an anonymous type, If you want a result with the same type as the items in ListA (let's say they are of class A), change the last part of the join:

```
 (a, b) => new A()           // when they match, take the a and the b
 {                           // to create a new object of class A
    Id = a.Id,
    Name = a.Name,
    Summary = b.Value,
 });
```